# Why is loading this file slow

Tags: lua

I have noticed that loading this file

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kikito/sha1.lua/f607d523c133c08ab8e35cc6507e81273bb80053/sha1.lua

is very slow (using Lua 5.1).

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/lua
require("sha1")
print("Hello")
```

running this gives:

```
$ time ./test.lua 
Hello

real    0m0.774s
user    0m0.760s
sys     0m0.012s
```

When removing the `require()` line, it gets down dramatically:

```
$ time ./test.lua 
Hello

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Which part is taking so long for the file to load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says right in the file:

```
-- loading this file (takes a while but grants a boost of factor 13)
local PRELOAD_CACHE = true
```

Set that to false and it will load faster but run slower.

Comment: I had trouble finding out where the slowness actually results from. But I see - the function definitions are function calls that define the function.